# Why is php reading a backslash?

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I have a code that saves data to a cookie. and the data saved in the cookie is like this:

```
(%22Lynyrd%20Skynyrd%22%3D%3Earray(%226983887641%22)%2C%20(%22Rod%20Stewart%22%3D%3Earray(%2259088763306%22)%2C%20(%22Led%20Zeppelin%20Official%22%3D%3Earray(%22131572223581891%22)%2C%20(%22Black%20Sabbath%22%3D%3Earray(%2256848544614%22)%2C%20(%22Hadag%20Nahash%20%D7%94%D7%93%D7%92%20%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A9%22%3D%3Earray(%22116542622632%22)%2C%20
```

and when i read it with this php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE["currentsearchctrl"])) {
        $cookz = $_COOKIE["currentsearchctrl"];
        echo $cookz;

    } else {
        echo 'cookie not set';
    } ?>
```

It returns with this:

```
(\"Lynyrd Skynyrd\"=>array(\"6983887641\"), (\"Rod Stewart\"=>array(\"59088763306\"), (\"Led Zeppelin Official\"=>array(\"131572223581891\"), (\"Black Sabbath\"=>array(\"56848544614\"), (\"Hadag Nahash הדג נחש\"=>array(\"116542622632\"),
```

The problem are the backslashes. I was going to: $data = array($cookz); but it doesn't work.

any ideas?

Comment: You can use `str_replace` on the '\"', but it would be a better idea to serialize and deserialize your data directly instead of using array at the end. For example you can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because **[magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)** is enabled on the host. It's a horrible "feature" and everybody wishes it would just die.

If you can edit php.ini on the server, set `magic_quotes_gpc = Off` and `magic_quotes_runtime = Off`.

Otherwise, if Apache is the HTTP server, there is a `.htaccess` trick you can use, documented [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Otherwise, you have to use [`stripslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to get data back to normal. Here is the include'd script I use to disable magic quotes when it isn't possible to disable it another way:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function array_stripslashes(&$array) {
        foreach($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                array_stripslashes($array[$k]);
            } else {
                $array[$k] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    array_stripslashes($_GET);
    array_stripslashes($_POST);
    array_stripslashes($_COOKIE);
    array_stripslashes($_REQUEST);
}

set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

most probably you have enabled [magic_quotes_gpc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc),
as it escape double quote for GET,POST,COOKIE

Answer (score 0):

%22 is HTML for " and PHP is delimiting these quotes with a backslash. See this for more info: http://aaroncameron.net/article.html?aID=59

You can turn this feature off, or you can remove slashes yourself.

Comment: I wouldn't say PHP is delimiting them.  More like escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way.

To write away a cookie use something like, write the $cookievalue to the array.

```
$cookievalue = implode("|", $array);
```

and retrieve the data, and put it back into an array:

```
$cookieArray = explode("|", $_COOKIE['cookie']);
```